# Limit processes resources usage with (PowerShell) script

Tags: powershell, memory, central-processing-unit, resources

(Sorry for duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57704486/limit-processes-resources-usage-with-powershell-script)

I'm setting up a shared computer (up to 50 concurrent users) and I'd like to anticipate one obvious future remark from my users: "it's too slow when my colleague is executing his job"

The server (running Windows 2016) will be mainly used to run various heavy softwares and I'm looking for a solution that could deal with "quota" or so.

Let me take a simplified example: Server has 512GB RAM and 10 cores. Only one user is connected, he can use up to 500GB RAM and 10 cores (100% CPU) Suddenly, another user is connected, the software/script will cut the resources of the first one in half so both users will have 50% RAM/50% CPU

We could imagine a smarter solution that analyze the behaviour of User 2: if he does nothing (like afk) compared to user1 (doing heavy whatever), then resources will be 90% for user1 and 10% for user2, ...

I'm looking for such thing. 
Either a already developed solution that could monitor and act without any human intervention or any tip so I can develop it myself. I thought about PowerShell (because Windows) but so far, 
I can't find any way to limit another process using it.

I found WSRM but this is not applicable on W2016 and the replacement (hyper-V) is not an option

Comment: This may be of some help: https://superuser.com/a/214572/333601

Comment: Concerning the CPU, there are indeed few applications.
I managed to build mine using PowerShell and playing with the CPU affinity. At the time I'm writting this, I don't have enough feedback to say if it's a good or an evil thing but it does the job. Concerning the RAM, no luck so far